# Slow java JVM start after 7u45

Tags: java, performance, applet

First of all some background: I have a small applet that is loaded as part of a broader web application. For most users the applet is loaded, checked and active very quickly regardless of whether it is locally cached or not. The start up time is typically under 3 seconds but for some people the start up time is upwards of 100 seconds.

All of my users are running Windows 7 SP1 with Trend anti-virus (3rd gen core i5 processors and either 4gb or 8gb of memory). The AV doesn't make any difference, I've tried it with and without and nothing changes.

What does make a difference is whether or not certificate checking is enforced. If I turn off the option to check for revocation the load time is always sub 3 seconds but this is not a valid option.

The java console loads pretty much instantly and watching the console I can see it does nothing for a long time then goes off to various ocsp services to acquire revocation information.  The delay all happens before it goes off to check though. Occasionally before the certificate check I can see a check for updates against oracle.com, this too suffers a long delay before starting so I am not inclined to put this down to *just* a CRL check.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing the delay and why turning off the certificate revocation check should make sure a drastic difference to the performance (or rather why the CRL check should be so slow on some machines)?

Comment: Maybe the checks invoke querying external servers which you can't reach from the client machines?

Comment: Erm ... you should be moving away from applets ...

Comment: I should add that I don't have any choice on the applets. I didn't create them, I just have to make sure they work. Their sole purpose is to provide desktop interaction for javascript

Comment: I have used fiddler and then wireshark to identify any traffic coming from Java but there is nothing that relates to Java that I can see